# Does lseek64 incur any device specific action?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have noticed that when I call lseek64 on my block device driver file (/dev/mybd), it always fails. (I can open, read and write on /dev/mybd ok).

However, if I can lseek64 with the same argument on /dev/sdb, which is an sata disk, it always succeed.

Does lseek requires any block device support? Or is it a pure kernel function?

Comment: Yes it does. What did you try?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So what should I do to make my device driver support lseek?

Comment: I'm not a kernel expert. Did you read http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-16-sect-2

Comment: yes, I did. Nothing related to lseek. Why do you say lseek needs block device driver support?

Comment: Because block devices are seekable, so something needs to implement the seek.

Comment: Actually that's not true. Seek is changing an offset related to a file structure. . It doesn't require block device involvement. And I figured out why my lseek is failing. It's because insmod hasn't finished yet

Comment: lseek *may* involve hardware. Whether the seek is done instantly or is deferred until the next read/write call is up to the driver code.

Comment: @jørgensen Could you explain more or point me to the code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code, the default seek for block devices is in `fs/block_dev.c`:

```
static loff_t block_llseek(struct file *file, loff_t offset, int origin)
{
        struct inode *bd_inode = file->f_mapping->host;
        loff_t size;
        loff_t retval;

        mutex_lock(&bd_inode->i_mutex);
        size = i_size_read(bd_inode);

        retval = -EINVAL;
        switch (origin) {
                case SEEK_END:
                        offset += size;
                        break;
                case SEEK_CUR:
                        offset += file->f_pos;
                case SEEK_SET:
                        break;
                default:
                        goto out;
        }
        if (offset >= 0 && offset <= size) {
                if (offset != file->f_pos) {
                        file->f_pos = offset;
                }
                retval = offset;
        }
out:
        mutex_unlock(&bd_inode->i_mutex);
        return retval;
}
```

No call to the specific block device. The only particular call is to `i_size_read`, that just does some SMP magic.

Answer (score 0):

lseek is a system call. And it is kernel specific. You have to implement this function for your device and should add in the "file_operations" structure of the device driver in llseek call.

In the file_operation structure all the device related functions will be mapped with the related system calls. Like read, write, open all will be linked with specific device driver code. So whenever you call those functions, the kernel will run the device driver's code linked with the call. If the device driver never implements a call, the corresponding value will be specified as NULL. In this case, if you call the NULL specified call, the call will always fail.

But in lseek, if 'file_operations' structure link is NULL, the kernel will work on the 'file' structure pointer to the file position. This may produce unpredictable outcome. But anyway the call will work (as per linux device drivers from o'relley publication).

So I'm not sure what is the real problem here. So if you didn't really implement the lseek call still, implement and try it once again.